# Login at dockerhub on Windows 10 with Ansible

Tags: windows, docker, ansible

I have to setup several Windows 10 PCs with Ansible. Therefore, I have to download and run docker images from dockerhub. But when I connect to the PCs per SSH I can not login on dockerhub:

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
```

How can I store the credentials for pulling the images without being able to use the credential manager? I perform the login with an ansible.windows.win_powershell task because docker_login task causes an exception somewhere in python.

Has anyone a solution for this problem?

Kind regards,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

In the docker config (C:\Users\username.docker\config.json) replace `"credsStore": "wincred"` with `"credsStore": ""`

The issue is discussed here: https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1263